# Error on specifying columns and tables in source in dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying the specify the query on the Datasource in dataflow as show on the below screen capture.

[image]

But it is throwing an error, is this the correct way of specifying the columns?

[image]

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> at Source '***': Incorrect syntax near '***'. SQL Server error encountered while reading from the given table or while executing the given query

This error message is because of the syntax error in the SQL query.

- Do not write the queries within double quotes.
- In the select query, while giving the column names `comma(,)` is missing between email and *.
  This is the reason for your error.
- Even if you are giving comma in the query, you will get the below error.

> at Source 'source1': The column 'name' was specified multiple times for 'T_***'.

- The reason is, when * is specified, all columns will be displayed. Column `name` is specified explicitly in the query also. It will result in two columns with the same name, and this is not allowed in dataflow.
- Thus, it is recommended to give either `select * from <table-name>` or `select<column-name[s]> from <table-name>` as a query in Query text box.